# Error inserting data into SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# Winform app witch uses the following SQL insert code but for some reason i get an error, the statement is:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (desemp.Text != "" && valu.Text != "" && fs.Text != "" && sel.Text != "" && desc.Text != "" && ench.Text != "" && comp.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.vidros(desempenho,valu,fs,sel,desc,enchimento,compo) values (@desemp,@valu,@fs,@sel,@desc,@ench,@comp)", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desemp", desemp.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valu", valu.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fs", fs.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sel", sel.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", desc.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ench", ench.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comp", comp.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("sucess!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error!");
            }
        }
```

The error i get is: Incorrect Syntax near the word 'desc'.
I lost hours trying to figure this one out and cant find the fault.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `desc` is a reserved word, for ordering.

Comment: Is it because `desc` is a keyword?

Comment: `desc` is indeed a keyword. Use `[desc]` (with square brackets) if you really want to stick to it, although, I would not recommend it.

Comment: @JonSkeet yup that got rid of the error but for some reason the insert does not work, i get a sucess message but no data got into the DB

Comment: you may also need to add `cmd.CommandType` before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Perhaps it is time you used the SQL Server Profiler (or the equivalent tool if you are working with another RDBMS). Is the statement actually executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy and paste that SQL code into your management studio, you will see that "desc" is highlighted meaning that it is a reserved keyword, used for ordering queries.

Just change desc to [desc] and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SqlParameter[] Prms = new SqlParameter[] {
            new SqlParameter("desemp", desemp.Text),
            new SqlParameter("valu", valu.Text),
            new SqlParameter("fs", fs.Text),
            new SqlParameter("sel", sel.Text),
            new SqlParameter("desc", desc.Text),
            new SqlParameter("ench", ench.Text),
            new SqlParameter("comp", comp.Text),
        };


cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Prms);
```

**Check the cell names and use them like this.**

Comment: This is just a different way to add parameters.  This answer doesn't address the error.

Answer (score 0):

A Button Click Event, using textBoxes, may look like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());
    try
    {
        string query = "insert into UserDetail(Name,Address) 
        values('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "');";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        con.Open();
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblmessage.Text = "Data saved successfully.";
    }
    catch
    {
        con.Close();
        lblmessage.Text = "Error while saving data.";
    }
```